# How can I create a block of code that turns an integer into a string that has the ordinal number?

Tags: python-3.x, indexing

I've been trying to create a block of code that outputs a string with the ordinal number when given an integer.

```
number = int(input('input a number'))

number = str(number)

if number[-2] == 1:
    ordinalnumber = str(number) + 'th'
elif number[-1] == 1:
    ordinalnumber = str(number) + 'st'
elif number[-1] == 2:
    ordinalnumber = str(number) + 'nd'
elif number[-1] == 3:
    ordinalnumber = str(number) + 'rd'
else:
    ordinalnumber = str(number) + 'th'

print(ordinalnumber)
```

My code takes an integer input, turns it into a string, then puts it through these if statements. The first one is meant to give any number with a 1 in the tens place a 'th' at the end. The second, third, and fourth are meant to give a number with a 1, 2, or 3, at their end an 'st', 'nd', or 'rd' respectively. The fifth is meant to give all other numbers a 'th' at their end.

Everything just outputs (number) + 'th', or something like 31th.
I know that it's the last line of code that is suffixing the 'th'.

Sorry if this is a really silly question, I only started programming 5 days ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the comparison you are doing is an integer with a string. `number[-2]` is a string whereas `1` is an integer.

So either compare the number[-2] with a string `"1"` or convert the `number[-2]` to an integer `int(number[-2])`

Also you should probably add some logic that checks whether the number is a single digit or not, because the `number[-2]` comparison will cause an error if the inputted number is a single digit.